# Yii2 autologin doesn't work

Tags: authentication, cookies, yii, yii2

I try to realize the autologin feature in yii2.

So I've enabled autologin in configuration:

```
'user' => [
    'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
    'enableAutoLogin' => true,
    'loginUrl' => ['account/login', 'account', 'account/index'],
],
```

Also I've added rememberMe field in form configuration

```
public function scenarios() {
    return [
        'login' => ['username','password','rememberMe'],
        'activate' => ['password','passwordrepeat'],
        'register' => ['username', 'mail'],
        'setup' => ['username', 'password', 'passwordrepeat', 'mail', 'secretkey'],
    ];
}
// ...
[
    ['rememberMe'], 
    'boolean',
    'on' => 'login',
],
```

I'm using this now at login:

```
public function login() {
    //var_dump((bool) ($this->rememberMe)); exit();
    if (!$this->validate()) {
        return false;
    }

    return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), (bool) ($this->rememberMe) ? 3600*24*30 : 0);
}
```

If I log in, users function getAuthKey function is called and a new auth_key is generated.

```
public function generateAuthKey() {
    $this->auth_key = Yii::$app->getSecurity()->generateRandomString();
    Helper::save($this);
    // Helper is a database helper which will update some rows like last_modified_at and similar in database
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function getAuthKey()
{
    $this->generateAuthKey();
    return $this->auth_key;
}
```

But always, I log in, it doesn't set some cookie variables.
My cookies are always

```
console.write_line(document.cookie)
# => "_lcp=a; _lcp2=a; _lcp3=a"
```

And if I restart my browser I'm not logged in.
What am I doing wrong?

It seems that Yii doesn't work with cookies correctly:

```
var_dump(Yii::$app->getRequest()->getCookies()); exit();
```

Results in:

```
object(yii\web\CookieCollection)#67 (2) { ["readOnly"]=> bool(true) ["_cookies":"yii\web\CookieCollection":private]=> array(0) { } }
```

If I access via `$_COOKIE` I have the same values as in JS.

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you resolve your problem?

Comment: no, but i dont worked on it since the mothods here does not help and i havent had time to work at this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you don't have to generate auth key every time in your getAuthKey method. Your app tries to compare database value to the auth key stored in your cookie. Just generate it once before user insert:

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function getAuthKey()
{
    return $this->auth_key;
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function beforeSave($insert)
{
    if (!parent::beforeSave($insert)) {
        return false;
    }
    if ($insert) {
        $this->generateAuthKey();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What if the auth key is always generated correctly? I can see it in the DB and in cookie also. Cookie also has the proper expiration date. Nevertheless, I never get signed in automatically. I have set `'enableAutoLogin' => true` and all the other methods are as default. So it should work. I read somewhere that calling `Yii::$app->user->identity` should trigger cookie login, but it doesn't. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Could be your timeout for autologin is not set 
Check if you have a proper assignment to the value assigned to the variable:

$authTimeout;
$absoluteAuthTimeout;

[See for more](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-user.html)

Comment: mhm... i tried it as you said and it dont work :/     `'user' => ['identityClass' => 'app\models\User','enableAutoLogin' => true,'authTimeout' => 3600 * 30 * 24,'absoluteAuthTimeoutParam' => '_identity',],` - I also tried `authTimeoutParam` but it seems not to work too