# Yii2 autologin with cookie

Tags: yii2, autologin

I've set up cookie based login just like the guy [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30556419/yii2-autologin-dont-work). I can see that auth key is always generated correctly. I can see it in the DB and in cookie also. Cookie also has the proper expiration date. Nevertheless, I never get signed in automatically. I have set `'enableAutoLogin' => true` and all the other methods are as default. So it should work. I read somewhere that calling `Yii::$app->user->identity` should trigger cookie login, but it doesn't. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Do you set duration for login method?
Method [User::login()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-user.html#login()-detail) has second argument named "duration". By default it is `0`. It mean the identity information will be stored in session as long as the session remains active. If you want autologin, set duration > 0.

Comment: Yes, as I stated in the initial question, the duration is defined. You can can clearly see that in the cookie where the cookie expiration date is exactly the duration that I am using in the config.

Comment: @jeesus Can you show full code (action and model)? May be on githus gist.

Comment: This is my User model: http://pastebin.com/GTyHYXVd
This is my LoginForm model: http://pastebin.com/xxDjWYKL
This is my SiteController: http://pastebin.com/UXZmpumb

Comment: @jeesus You should not call the loginByCookie() in controller by hand. It called automaticaly when you try to get UserIdentity. [Look](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-basic/blob/master/controllers/SiteController.php#L50) for a sample yii2 application. There is no calling of loginByCookie().

Comment: I just added it because it wasn't working without it. And it isn't working with it. So I'm in trouble anyway. Any other ideas?

Comment: I uploaded the copy of related files to [GitHub](https://github.com/jeesus/yii2/tree/master/cookie-login). The cookie is refreshed on every login, but for some reason `validateAuthKey()` seems never to be called.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be caused by data retrieved from cookie. The $id parameter in User::findIdentity  was not a MongoId or string but an array. Simplest solution is to overwrite the method e.g:

```
public static function findIdentity($id)
{
if(!empty($id) && is_array($id))
$id = new \MongoId($id['$id']);
return static::findOne($id);
}
```

Comment: Actually the problem is solved for now. I had set a custom `$identityCookie` and for some reason the autoLogin feature didn't work when it was set. Removing it cleared the problem for me.